# Visual Studio design view doesn't recognize nth-child css selectors

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, css-selectors

Is there any way to get Visual Studio 2012 to correctly render `nth-child` selectors in the Design view? Neither of the following selectors are translated to the design view.

```
    table tr td:last-child {
        width:35px;
    }

    table tr td:nth-child(2) {
        width:35px;
    }
```

Oddly the `first-child` selector is recognized and displays correctly. Are there any extension I can use to improve CSS translation when working in the IDE?

Comment: Strange. What version of Windows and IE is your development box running?

Comment: Windows 8 Pro and Chrome version 30.0.1599.69 m. Everything looks fine when running in the browser, just not in VS.

Comment: @QF_Developer - the version of Chrome is irrelevant. I believe Visual Studio uses the installed version of IE to it's rendering.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisF I have IE 10 installed but even there the CSS still renders correctly. Is this an isolated problem with my system? Does everyone else see these CSS examples displaying correctly in VS?